# Limit Exceed while trying to store a large html text format into nvarchar(MAX) field for product

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar

I'm trying to store product description through tinymce text editor into sql-server. But at the time of insert it thowing error that nvarchar can't converted to bigint.
I have taken nvarchar(MAX) for the description field.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to show all your relevant code if you want help - we can't debug it without seeing it!

Comment: Reading this will also help you write a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

nvarchar(max) can handle 2GB of text. I don't suppose the description column would ever be that big? So chances are, the issue in not nvarchar, or the size (max) you used.

The error seems to suggest that at one point, in your code, you are trying to parse a nvarchar into a bigint value. It may or may not be relevant to the description field though.

But I agree with others, without seeing the code, there isn't much one can do to debug it.